# ElasticSearch QueryBuilder must_not clause strange behaviour

Tags: java, elasticsearch

According to documentation

> **must_not** The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents.

I have query like this:

```
// searching for URI which contains smart and doesn't contain vip.vs.csin.cz
BoolQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
builder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(URI, "smart")));
builder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.termQuery(URI, "vip.vs.csin.cz")));
```

There're two URIs im my elasticsearch repository

1)

> /smart-int-vip.vs.csin.cz:5080/smart/api/runtime/case/SC0000000000558648/record/generate/4327/by/SMOBVA002/as/true?espisRecordForm=ANALOG&accountNumber=2318031033/0800

2)

> /smart/api/runtime/case/SC0000000000558648/record/generate/4327/by/SMOBVA002/as/true?espisRecordForm=ANALOG&accountNumber=2318031033/0800

When I execute query via **ElasticSearchTemplate**

```
elasticsearchTemplate.getClient().search(searchRequest);
```

I get back **0 records**. When I execute same query without **mustNot** clause I get back **2 records.**
In kibana I can write:

```
uri: "smart" NOT uri: "vip.vs.csin.cz"
```

And get **1 record** as expected.
I was expecting the same behaviour from Java ElasticSearchClient. How can I filter records which contains "vip.vs.csin.cz" from Java and why It filtered second record even though it doesn't contain anything from mustNot clause I specified ?

Edit here's my mapping

```
@Document(indexName = "audit-2018", type = "audit")
public class Trace {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String uri;

    // more columns, getter & setters
}
```

Comment: It we will be much more beneficial if you also share mapping of the index.

Comment: I added mapping of my index, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code you've provided shows a bool query using the `must` and `must_not` clauses, wherein you are doing a term query. The thing about term queries is that they are subject to the analyzer you have on your fields, the standard analyzer for `text` (which is the data type of your `uri` field, [read more here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#text)) fields will remove all punctuation (in other words the dots in your word) and split your word up. `vip.vs.csin.cz` becomes `vip vs csin cz`. The `text` field type should be reserved for full-text searches only, in you case I would go for `keyword` field type ([read more here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword)) The reason your Kibana query works as expected is because that one is not actually doing a terms query, but rather a [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query containing a lucene query: `uri: "smart" NOT uri: "vip.vs.csin.cz"`.

So you have a couple of options to fix your problem. You could change your terms query to `match_phrase` queries, which would allow you to retain the order of your tokenized terms and probably net the correct result. An alternative would be to do a `query_string` query instead of a terms query in your Java code, since you have already determined that this does give you the correct result.

My proposed solution would however be to reindex with `uri` being of field type `keyword`, since this field type will not result in unwanted tokenization of you field values into multiple terms. You can read more about the default analyzer and tokenizer for the `keyword` field type [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html#_definition_5). This would save you headache in the future since you know that your queries are matching your field values exactly "as is".